# How to select specific row in SQL from a bad designed schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I have a string in a column of a db schema I did not design, like this:

```
numbers column
--------------------
First:   1,2,33,34,43,5 
Second:  1,2,3,4,5
```

Despite I know this is not the best practice scenario, I would still want to select the row which contains only '3' value, not '33' or '34' or '43'.
How could I select only second row?

```
SELECT *
FROM tblNumbers   
WHERE numbers like '%,3,%' OR numbers like '3,%'  OR numbers  like '%,3'
```

This query selected both 2 columns. How can I do this, to get just the second row?

Here is my problem:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Excellent example to illustrate why one should not store comma separated value in a column

Comment: Why don't you normalize your table? Every column should contains only one information.

Comment: `number like '% 3,%' or number like '% 3 %'`?

Comment: Btw, it's gettting even worse if someone says that you should support decimal values and that customer is f.e. a german. He will provide numbers like `1,2` which is a single number. How do you want to store that in your column?

Comment: I didn't create this table

Comment: @user5535577: that's not an answer to the question why you don't fix it.

Comment: @user5535577: but your current sql returns only the second row, so i idn't understand your issue

Comment: @TimSchmelter the query returns first row, too

Comment: @user5535577: no, only the second. Maybe you have simplified it somehow.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I added a pic

Comment: @user5535577: I have seen it, but it's correct that you get the second row, because it also contains a `,Y` at the end. If you would remove it the row would be omitted.

Comment: @TimSchmelter look at twice row. YY value returned.

Comment: @user5535577: have you read my comment at all? ;-) The second row is included, but not because of `YY` but because of the `Y` at the end

Comment: @user5535577 Hahahahaha I am stupit man.

Answer (score 1):

You should be storing the values in a separate table, with one row per column and per number.

Sometimes, though, we are stuck with other peoples bad data structures.  If so, you can do what you want in this rather cumbersome way:

```
where replace(replace(numbers, '{', ','), '}', ',') like '%,3,%'
```

That is, put the delimiters around all the numbers in `numbers`.

Let me repeat, though:  the proper way to store this data is using a separate table.  If you need to store multiple values in a column like this, then do some research on XML and JSON formats (which are supported only in the most recent version of SQL Server).

EDIT:

Exactly the same idea applies, the code is just simpler:

```
where ',' + numbers + ',' like '%,3,%'
```

Comment: You should mention that OP just didn't realize that the second row is included because of the `,Y` at the end not because of the `YY` in the middle. At the end his query was working and the question ca be closed as a problem that can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM tblNumbers   
WHERE number = '3' OR ReportedGMY = '3'
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense if I'm honest. First of all **number** doesn't need to be part of the `WHERE` clause and second of all you've repeated **ReportedGMY** twice in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: i edited it .. i included the number and reportedGMY because she wants to select from both column..

Answer (score 0):

if you are storing numbers as integers

```
SELECT *
FROM tblNumbers   
WHERE number = '3'
```

if you are storing as string

```
SELECT *
FROM tblNumbers   
WHERE number like "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its is bad practice to save command separated value in a column. This should be avoid as much as possible. If you really need to do it, then can be done using user defined function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.HasDigit (@String VARCHAR(MAX), @DigitToCheck INT, @Delimiter VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DelimiterPosition INT
    DECLARE @Digit INT
    DECLARE @ContainsDigit BIT = 0

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String) > 0
    BEGIN
            SELECT @DelimiterPosition = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String)
            SELECT @Digit = CAST(SUBSTRING(@String, 1, @DelimiterPosition - 1) AS INT)
            IF(@Digit = @DigitToCheck) 
            BEGIN
                SET @ContainsDigit = 1
            END
            SELECT @String = SUBSTRING(@String, @DelimiterPosition + 1, LEN(@String) - @DelimiterPosition)
    END
    RETURN @ContainsDigit
END;
GO


CREATE TABLE TEST (
    Numbers VARCHAR(MAX),
    COLUMNNAME VARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('First:', '1,2,33,34,43,5')
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('Second:', ' 1,2,3,4,5')
GO


SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE dbo.HasDigit(COLUMNNAME, 3, ',') = 1
```

Output:

```
--Numbers       COLUMNNAME
---------       ----------------
--Second:       1,2,3,4,5
```